# runtime ( or maybe logical ) error when implementing linked list in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

A linked list is a linear data structure where each element is a separate object. Each element (we will call it a node) of a list is comprising of two items - the data and a reference to the next node. The last node has a reference to null.
so i tried to make a simple linked list ( not doubly or circular ) in c++ and here is my code. i run it with xcode and there's no problem in syntax. i added a node with key 1 and data "asd". i tried to print elements of the list but what i see is : (lldb)
what's the problem ?
thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class node {
    friend class linkedlist;
private:
    int key;
    string data;
    node *next;
public:
    node(int k,string d){
        this->key=k;
        this->data=d;
    }

};
class linkedlist{
private:
    node *head;
    node *last;
public:
    linkedlist(){
        this->head=NULL;
        this->last=NULL;
    }
    inline bool is_empty() {return head==NULL;}
    void print(){
        cout<<"\n";
        node *current;
        for(current=this->head;current!=NULL;current=current->next){
            cout<<"("<<current->key<<","<<current->data<<")"<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    void insert(int k,string d){
        node *new_node=new node(k,d);
        this->last->next=new_node;
        this->last=new_node;
        if(this->is_empty()) this->head=new_node;
    }
};


int main()
{
    linkedlist *list=new linkedlist();
    list->insert(1,"asd");
    list->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insert` function you are trying to access a NULL object:

```
this->last->next=new_node;
```

Your list is empty i.e. `head` and `last` are NULL.

Comment: thank you dude :) i corrected it by adding if(!this->is_empty()) in the beginning of that line and now my program works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't analyze the list implementation, but perhaps this matters in main: `list->insert(1, string("asd"));`